# Objective-C destructor with ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, destructor

I'm trying to create some cleanup code in my Objective-C class, by overwriting dealloc:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    //cleanup code
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Though I cannot do this since `[super dealloc]` is disallowed by the compiler when ARC is enabled. Is there an alternative I can use?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) (emphasis mine):

> **You may implement a dealloc method if you need to manage resources other than releasing instance variables.** You do not have to (indeed you cannot) release instance variables, but you may need to invoke [systemClassInstance setDelegate:nil] on system classes and other code that isn’t compiled using ARC.
>
> Custom dealloc methods in ARC **do not require a call to [super dealloc] (it actually results in a compiler error). The chaining to super is automated and enforced by the compiler.**

So you can do the same sort of cleanup in `dealloc` when using ARC, just don't call `super`.

Answer (score 6):

When ARC is active you simply don't call `[super dealloc]`. ARC will do this for you. Alternately, you could have a `prepareForDealloc` method that allows you to call `super` and which is called from within `dealloc` in your base class.